# R: rgl 3D plots bounding box faces colors and strokes

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

I am currently doing simple 3D plots with rgl and ***persp3d()***. I tried to use ***bbox3d()*** but I cannot make the stroke around the box (the 3 planes in the back/bottom) appearing (similarly to ***axes3d()***):

[image]

The problem with ***axes3d()*** is that the bounding box/planes are not filled with a color (at least I do not know how to achieve that).
Thank for your time!

Here is the code to produce the **Actual** version:

```
library("rgl")
x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
y=x
z=outer(x,y,function(x,y){x+y})
persp3d(x,y,z,col="grey")
bbox3d(lwd=5,box=T,color=c("grey","black"))
```

Comment: can you add them both?

Comment: can you add a [mcve] for the plot on the left?

Comment: Done :) I can't do both at the same time. The call to one, erase the other.

Comment: After investigating the parameters of bbox and coming back to this I’m now uncertain what is actually being requested. (I’m sympathetic to persons who have  English as a second or third language.) It is possible to set colors for the “sides panels” of the bbox-created plot. Is that what is being requested?

Comment: I think what's being requested is the thick black lines along the axes in the right-hand plot.  (It would be more obvious if these were coloured red (or something) for contrast ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get pretty close using `segments3d` with `margin` and `floating` properties.  For example:

```r
library("rgl")
x=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
y=x
z=outer(x,y,function(x,y){x+y})
open3d()
#> glX 
#>   1
persp3d(x,y,z,col="grey", axes=FALSE)
limits <- par3d("bbox")
bbox3d(col=c("gray", "black"), polygon_offset = 1)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="x++",
           floating = TRUE)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="x--",
           floating = TRUE)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="y++",
           floating = TRUE)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="y--",
           floating = TRUE)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="z++",
           floating = TRUE)
segments3d(x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           y=0, z=0,
           lwd=5, margin="z--",
           floating = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[image: screenshot]

It's not perfect, because the segments don't render nicely at the corners, and it looks like there's a bug in the initial display before you do any rotation.  The funny coordinate system for margin objects is described in the `?mtext3d` help topic.